# Bootstrapper Manifest Generator for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, mysql, setup-project, bootstrapper

I'm looking for Bootstrapper Manifest Generator for VS2010. Where can I download it? I want to include MySQL installer in my C# setup project in the way I include Net Framework. Can you help me?